# pytest dynamically generate cases by comparing 2 lists

Tags: python, pytest

I am having so much trouble in dynamically generating pytest test cases. here is the scenario.

I have 2 lists with string elements

```
List1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
List2 = ['a', 'c', 'd']
```

I want to compare these 2 lists and compare first element from List1 with first element of List2.

For instance if first element from List1 'a' == first element from List2 'a' then it's a PASS. Now 2nd element from List1 does not match with 2nd element from List2 so it should throw FAIL in this case 'b' != 'c'

I am not sure how to write pytest test case for this. These 2 lists are long lists with too many elements
this is what I am doing

```py
def list1():
    for i in some_csv:
        list1.append(i)

def list2():
    for i in some_csv:
        list2.append(i)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("list1", list1())
def test_validation(list1):
    assert list1 in list2()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to return a value in your functions. Also, it is not a good idea to use the same name for your function (`list1`) and the variable that contains a list element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just compare the list directly?

```py
assert list1() == list2()
```

But if you insist on testing element-wise:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "one, two",             # these are the args of the test case
    zip(list1(), list2()),  # generate tuples to unpack into the args
)
def test_element(one, two):
    assert one == two
```

The test names will be messy, though. You may want to provide a list / iterator to `ids` to make the names look nicer.

Answer (score 0):

In a first time you forgot the return in each list method.
In a second time the test is not the test you describe.
prametrize will loop over the result of list1() this mean you will compare if 'a' is in the result of list2().
Exemple

```
'a' in ['a', 'c', 'd']
```

Using in could introduce some issue for examle

```
List1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
List2 = ['a', 'c', 'd' 'b']
'b' in list2() # This is True
```

My understanding of your issue is to compare the equality of the two list.To do it you can do

```
['a', 'b', 'c'] == ['a', 'c', 'd']
```

Your example will look like this

```
def list1():
    for i in some_csv:
        list1.append(i)
    return list1

def list2():
    for i in some_csv:
        list2.append(i)
    return list2

def test_validation():
    assert list1() == list2()
```

Best regards

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I use pytest.mark.parametrize decorator to compare the 2 list functions and generate dynamic test cases. For instance if first element of first list and first element of second list are equal then in console I should see PASSED and then if second element of first list and second element of second list doesn’t match then I should see FAILED.